# Controlling output in a Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script

When I run a shell script in bash, I push everything to a file as follows:

./script.sh >results.txt

Some of the commands in my script output to the terminal, rather than the text file.

For example, the line
cmd "ssh -V"
outputs to the terminal.

What can I do to get the results in the results.txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stderr is not redirected to the file. Most probably you need

```
./script.sh > results.txt 2>&1
```

to redirect both to results.txt. Note that

```
./script.sh 2>&1 >results.txt
```

is something different, as it redirects stdout to file and stderr to the non-redirected stdout. And of course you can substitute `&1` for a different file name.

If you are using bash you will get away with

```
./script.sh &>results.txt
```

Not that in all cases the interwoven stdout/stderr are not guaranteed to be in the same order as on the console. This will work for everything, not only bash scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you redirect **all** output to the text file.

- `stdout` with `>`
- `stderr` with `2>`

See more [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23320631/3857510).

Note that the script should start with:

```
#!/bin/bash
```